# Why does the value of a constant affect HLSL shader compilation?

Tags: xna, directx, xna-4.0, hlsl

I have an effect file in XNA4, being compiled as Shader Model 3.

This line compiles fine (interpolating between 2 colours):

```
return lerp(float4(1,0,0,1),float4(0,0,1,1),pf.x);
```

Changing the green component of the first colour from 0 to 0.5:

```
return lerp(float4(1,0.5,0,1),float4(0,0,1,1),pf.x);
```

Results in a failed compilation:

```
error X6045: When constant registers are read multiple times in a single 
instruction, the _abs modifier must either be present on all of the 
constants, or none of them.
```

Googling for the error code returns nothing *(edit: other than this question)*

Comment: Oh, it does return this question now ;-)

Comment: So what you're saying is that posting "google returns nothing" on the net is only ever true temporarily?

Comment: If you post on SO Google has the question indexed seconds later. It was just a curiosity I pointed out, no reason to edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) all of the values which are passed to `lerp()` should be of the same type and size, so maybe that will work:

```
return lerp(float4(1,0.5,0,1),float4(0,0,1,1),float4(pf.x,pf.x,pf.x,pf.x));
```

Comment: You can also use `pf.xxxx` instead of `float4(pf.x,pf.x,pf.x,pf.x)`.